# Is there a way to find out how many registered users logged in a given time period?

Tags: 6, users, nodes

I am working on KPIs for my site and there are a few numbers I want to track. One of them is how many registered users actually logged in every month. Is there a way to get this number?

Answer (score 1):

You could count all User table rows in the database where the fields for "Last Access" and or "Last Login" are newer than one month old .  You'd need to compare those timestamps to a timestamp for the start of the current month. [You can find that with something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3634090/443779) or maybe it's as simple as:

```
$this_month_start = strtotime("-1 month");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this module is what your looking for [User Stats](https://drupal.org/project/user_stats). Cheers.

Comment: thanks smtf! sorry, my understanding of user stats is that it provides statistics about individual users. What I am looking for is simply the number of people who have logged in during a given time period (e.g. a month).